# TLS Handshake Protocol for .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, ssl

I am using a .NET application(Client) that makes https calls onto a server. My application is based on .NET 4.5, so the Default TLS protocol used is TLS 1.0. To support all types of Protocols I have included this in my Code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Now things work fine for any configuration of server.

But I am not sure what this part of code does? Does it try with all the three and falls back to the compatible version? If yes, in what protocol version order does it try to create TLS Handshake?

Answer (score 1):

The [`SecurityProtocolType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enumeration marked with the `FlagsAttribute`.  In short, this allows its values to be combined in to one value, using the binary `|` (or) operator.  You can see some examples of how `FlagsAttribute` works from a mathematical standpoint [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Essentially, this line of code tells the the `ServicePointManager` that it is allowed to use one of the TLS versions listed in the enumeration.  It is documented to use the highest listed version supported by both sides of the connection (not including some tricks that attackers can use to mess with the handshake, documented in the RFC linked below).  If you *really* want to get in to exactly how it negotiates which version to use, you will have the read [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (for TLS 1.2), specifically [Section 7.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.3).

The `ServicePointManager` class in .NET doesn't actually directly control the protocol negotiation, other than specifying what versions it will allow.  It is really just a [wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380516(v=vs.85).aspx) around "schannel.dll", on windows, which is a native library .NET calls using p/Invoke.